# What are the different rules for capitalization of prepositions in titles?

Tags: prepositions, titles, style-manuals

There are probably different rules for different style guides, but I do have one question.

I have heard that the general rule is that any preposition less than four letters does not get capitalized, however, I have often seen prepositions of place (*on, at, in*) be capitalized in contexts where the rest of the prepositions are not (*from, to, for,* etc.).

Are prepositions of place an exception in any of the style guides?

Comment: Relevant article about how complicated this can get: [Wikipedia "Star Trek Into Darkness" controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_Star_Trek_Into_Darkness_controversy) :-)

Comment: Capitalization in titles -- indeed, everything in titles -- is not subject to general rule. Authors and editors do what they think is right, which could be anything at all. Who knows what nonsense they were taught about English?

Comment: This question is off-topic for three reasons: firstly, capitalisation in titles is a matter of *style* rather than English usage. Secondly, there's no right answer regarding style – merely opinion. Lastly, you're asking for a review of style guides, which *might be* (but probably isn't) on-topic on our [Writing.SE] site but certainly doesn't belong here on EL&U. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the short but valuable EL&U [Tour]. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes they just look like prepositions, but are not. That’s why even though one title with the word *in* in it would not capitalize that word, another would do so when *in* is not a preposition there.

Compare:

1. A Ringing in My Ears
2. Bringing In the Sheaves

In the first case, the word *in* is a preposition; its prepositional object is the noun phrase *my ears*.

In the second case, the word *in* is no longer a preposition, and *the sheaves* is most certainly not its prepositional object. Therefore it should be capitalized in the second case.

This can happen with articles, too.

3. Telling a Good Tale
4. When A Is for Aardvark

In the third case, *a* is an article and therefore uncapitalized.

In the fourth case, the same-spelled word is no longer an article but a noun, so it is capitalized.

The guidance that you don't capitalize articles or short prepositions still applies. It's just easy for people to mistake things that look the same but aren't one of those.